# Rasberry PI connect with 4 monitor

Tags: connectors

How to connect 4 monitor to 1 Rasberry PI 4 ?

Comment: just using 2 LCD monitor with HDMI port and another 2 LCD monitor with VGA port but using usb to VGA converter

Comment: basically the question is 
How to connect 4 monitor to 1 rasberry pi 4?

Comment: Ya that's the idea but it doesn't work with USB2VGA. no output after all. Do I need to do some config for it? because i cant find it on internet.

Comment: google `video wall` ... you can set up four monitors, feed the same video to all four, configure each of the monitors to display 1/4 of the screen

Comment: `it doesn't work with USB2VGA` ... why is your question not about that? ... you really need to figure out what your exact problem is and ask questions about the problem, not ask questions about the finished product .... it is like asking `how do i build a race car?` when in fact you do not know how to build wheels ............ good luck with your project

Comment: one other thing that you need to remember is that your question is about the Rpi only in part ..... it is really a Linux question

Comment: Well ya perhaps it just i heard that rasberry PI can only support 2 monitor so i wonder can it support 4 monitor cuz it's part of the project so let me get this straight.
Is it possible for 4 monitor to connect with one rasberry PI 4 with out using splitter ?

Comment: *i heard that rasberry PI can only support 2 monitor so i wonder can it support 4* - I heard my car can only do 100MPH so I was wondering if it can go 200MPH - that's what your statement sounds like

Comment: Okay okay look simple question to all is it possible for rasberry pi to support 4 monitor?

Comment: Please don't explain us in comments what your problem is. Instead [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/108036/edit) the question and and put it there. Otherwise you get down votes and risk to get closed.

Comment: sorry i am new here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspberry Pi 4 video supports dual 4k HDMI (micro hdmi sockets).  Also supported is composite output but it's not clear if this can be used simulataneously as the HDMI ports. It certainly wouldn't be desirable to do this due to processing overhead and visual quality differences between the HDMI and composite outputs.

Whilst it may be possible to additionaly use USB to HDMI (or VGA) outputs it's unlikely that there would be enough processing resource to make it practical.

2 monitors is the practical limit.